# How to get SFTP login alert (email or SMS) on ubuntu?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, unix, sftp

I want to get Email or/and SMS alert whenever someone logs into my server. I have successfully done this for SSH login by editing .bashrc file.
But this method doesn't work for SFTP login.
I know I can do this by extracting information from log files, but i want a more efficient way (Since users can delete from log file).
I have also tried [this](https://joshua14.homelinux.org/blog/?p=1764), but it doesn't work.(I'm using ubuntu 12.04).
Basically, I want to execute a curl command (SMS API) on successful login.
Please help, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you have the `sendmail` package (`sudo apt-get install sendmail`).

You can create or edit the file `/etc/ssh/sshrc` and give it the following code to achieve this:

```
ip=`echo $SSH_CONNECTION | cut -d " " -f 1`

logger -t ssh-wrapper $USER login from $ip  echo "User $USER logged in from $ip" | sendemail -q -u "Email Title" -f "Sender <from@server.com>" -t "Your Name <you@email.com>" -s smtp.server.com &
```

Fill the appropriate variables (sender and recipient names and addresses) into this code.

Comment: Sorry, that file is not available inside /etc/ssh/

Comment: You mean `sendmail`?